# Dictionary of filter function does not close

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, jupyter-notebook

I have some data (in a `pandas.DataFrame`), which I want to apply some filters to. I seemed proper to define a dictionary of filter functions, which for one case of filtering were supposed to be just constant comparisons, but I need flexibility of other boolean tests.
So I tried defining a filter like this.

In pure `Python 3.3.5`, this works.

```
>>> center = {"A": 1, "B": 0}
>>> filters = {key: (lambda x: x==value)
...   for key, value in center.items()}
>>> filters["A"](1)
True
```

In `IPython 2.3.0`, using that Python 3, it works as well.

```
In [1]: center = {"A": 1, "B": 0}

In [2]: filters = {key: (lambda x: x==value)
   ...:  for key, value in center.items()}

In [3]: filters["A"](1)
Out[3]: True
```

However, if I run this most simple test in an IPython notebook, I get

```
center = {"A": 1, "B": 0}
filters = {key: (lambda x: x==value)
           for key, value in center.items()}
print(filters["A"](1))
print(filters["B"](1))
print(filters["A"](0))
print(filters["B"](0))
```

gives

```
False
False
True
True
```

Apparently, in `ipython notebook`, the closure on `value` does not bind the current, but the last value of `value`, whereas in other python flavours, it does the opposite.

Why?

Comment: duplicate of, well, quite a few questions here, but http://stackoverflow.com/q/13355233/41316 is a good starting point. To make a long story short, you want `lambda x, value=value: x == value` to capture the value of `value` at lambda definition time - else it will look for the current (call time) value of `value`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to understand what I did, but it looks like it sometimes works and sometimes not, without the default argument trick. I'll give details, if I find that I'm not confusing things.

Comment: without the default argument trick, it will use whatever `value` is bound to **at call time** - so for at least one of the lambdas (the last created) it should _seem_ to work (unless of course you rebind `value` later on in the same scope <g>).

Comment: Bloody confirmation bias. It *seems* to behave in `ipy` and `py`, but only because, as you imply, the value for `A` is bound last, so I stopped testing. Argh. Self-Delete or Vote to Close as Duplicate?

Comment: Decisions, decisions... xD

Comment: The behaviour *was* non-deterministic, because the dict comprehension would iterate over the `center.items()` in an undefined order, and thus `value` could be either `0` or `1` afterwards. But in 3.6+, dictionaries are ordered, further complicating the example.