# Generating a 'sequence of dicts' for scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, minimize

I'm using scipy.optimize.minimize with constraints. The example in the documentation ( at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html ) uses for constraints:

```
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] - 2 * x[1] + 2},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[0] - 2 * x[1] + 6},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -x[0] + 2 * x[1] + 2})
```

I'd like to do something similar but generate the elements of this sequence in a loop, but I'm having trouble.

I've tried treating cons as a tuple, an example of the same form as above:

```
cons = (,)
for i in range(4):
    cons += ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] - 2 * x[1] + i})
```

but I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'dict'`.

I also tried using `str` and `eval`:

```
cons = (str({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] - 2 * x[1]}))
for i in range(3):
    cons += (str({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] - 2 * x[1] + i + 1}))
cons = eval(cons)
```

but that didn't work either, I get something like

```
cons = eval(cons)
  File "<string>", line 1
    {'fun': <function <lambda> at 0x062964F0>, 'type': 'eq'}{'fun': <function <lambda> at 0x062964F0>, 'type': 'eq'}{'fun': <function <lambda> at 0x062964F0>, 'type': 'eq'}{'fun': <function <lambda> at 0x062964F0>, 'type': 'eq'}
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Tuples are immutable**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Once you have created a tuple, you cannot modify the number of the elements in there, or their order.

**You can do that way:**

```
cons = []
for i in range(4):
    cons.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] - 2 * x[1] + i})
```

Which will give you a list of dictionaries. Once your list is done, if you want to change it into a tuple, you can do:

```
cons = tuple(cons)
```

The result:

```
>>> cons
({'fun': <function <lambda> at 0x106e2cb18>, 'type': 'ineq'},
    {'fun': <function <lambda> at 0x106e2cf50>, 'type': 'ineq'},
    {'fun': <function <lambda> at 0x106e335f0>, 'type': 'ineq'},
    {'fun': <function <lambda> at 0x106e33cf8>, 'type': 'ineq'})
```

--

*Note that [Raymond Hettinger](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) himself said [not so long ago](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/324664257004322817):*

> Generally, lists are for looping; tuples for structs. Lists are
>   homogeneous; tuples heterogeneous.Lists for variable length.

So in your case, you might want to keep the list unless a tuple is needed by some third-part module.

Comment: '...you cannot modify the number of the elements in there' - doesn't using cons += (stuff,) modify the number of elements in the tuple cons?

Comment: @JGM272 no it doesn't. It creates a new tuple and replaces the old one with the new one, just as if you did `cons = (previous,) + (new,)`. Anyway in your case, this is probably not the best (most pythonic) way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a dict (parentheses are not doing anything here):

```
for i in range(4):
    cons += ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] - 2 * x[1] + i})
```

add a tuple, adding a comma after the dict:

```
for i in range(4):
    cons += ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[0] - 2 * x[1] + i},)
>>> cons
({'fun': <function <lambda> at 0xb746de2c>, 'type': 'ineq'}, {'fun': <function <lambda> at 0xb747656c>, 'type': 'ineq'}, {'fun': <function <lambda> at 0xb74765a4>, 'type': 'ineq'}, {'fun': <function <lambda> at 0xb74765dc>, 'type': 'ineq'})
```

--

Note that as @Jivan indicates in its answer, you should use lists for this kind of job.

Comment: sorry I edited your answer instead of mine! wrong manip :) Feel free to reject the edit, of course.

Comment: Well, that was an nice edit so I accepted. I will change it though to go in your way.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but both of the proposed solutions seem wrong. Or am I missing something?

```
def generate_constraints_wrong(n_params):
    cons = []
    for i in range(n_params):
        cons.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[i]})
    return tuple(cons)

def generate_constraints_wrong2(n_params):
    cons = tuple()
    for i in range(n_params):
        cons += ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  x[i]},)
    return cons

def generate_constraints_right(n_params):
    # let's create a function generator that uses closure to pass i to the generated function
    def wrapper_fun(x, i):
        def fun(x):
            return x[i]
        return fun
    cons = []
    for i in range(n_params):
        f = wrapper_fun(x, i)
        cons.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': f})
    return tuple(cons)

# verify the generated functions
n_params = 3
x = [1,10, 100]
cons1 = generate_constraints_wrong(n_params)
cons2 = generate_constraints_wrong2(n_params)
cons3 = generate_constraints_right(n_params)
print(cons1[0]['fun'](x)) # this should be 1 but instead we end up modifying all of our lambda objects to have the last i
print(cons1[1]['fun'](x))
print(cons2[0]['fun'](x))
print(cons2[1]['fun'](x))
print(cons3[0]['fun'](x))
print(cons3[1]['fun'](x))
```

prints:

```
100
100
100
100
1
10
```

The problem is that the closure of each lambda points to the object i, rather than to the value the object i had at a particular loop iteration. For more details see:
[Python lambda closure scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355233/python-lambda-closure-scoping)