# list containing function objects(unique), return same value when called?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, lambda

I have this list containing function object that have different passed values ,
But end up printing same values.

```
>>> a=[]
>>> for i in range(5):
        a.append(lambda x:i**x)


>>> a
[<function <lambda> at 0x02F6B540>, <function <lambda> at 0x02F86E40>,
<function <lambda> at 0x02FBDED0>, <function <lambda> at 0x02FBDF18>,
<function <lambda> at 0x02FBDF60>]

>>> a[0]
<function <lambda> at 0x02F6B540>
>>> a[0](5)
1024
>>> a[1](5)
1024
>>> a[2](5)
1024
```

For every iteration the list supposed to contain `lambda` for every `i`

Comment: Because `i == 4` after loop.

Comment: The "closure" problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355233/python-lambda-closure-scoping..

Comment: @alecxe thanks for pointing out to the question , I have marked as duplicate.