# Invalid closure in Python's lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Consider this short code snippet:

```
class X:
    pass

xs = []
for s in ("one", "two", "three"):
    x = X()
    x.f = lambda: print(s)
    xs.append(x)

for x in xs:
    x.f()
```

It outputs:

```
three
three
three
```

I thought the result should be like this instead:

```
one
two
three
```

Why is that not the actual result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python lambda closure scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355233/python-lambda-closure-scoping)

Comment: Right, it's a duplicate. Thanks a lot for this link!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating functions in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda function holds reference to `s`, hence the last assigned value to s is printed when called outside that for loop. Try the below code for your expected behaviour. Here a copy of that existing reference `s` is created in `v` as function argument and that value is printed inside the function `f`.

```
class X:
    pass

xs = []
for s in ("one", "two", "three"):
    x = X()
    def f(v=s): print(v)
    x.f = f
    xs.append(x)

for x in xs:
    x.f()
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: You can even exchange `def f(v=s): print(v)` with `x.f = lambda v=s: print(v)`

Answer (score 2):

It happens because the `s` variable is a reference, not a value. And the value by reference will be resolved when it will be called, not created. To resolve the value in the creation time use the `default argument`.

```py
lambda s=s: print(s)
```