# Python doit: subtask yields same uptodate callable

Tags: python, doit

I have this code in `dodo.py`:

```py
def closed_over(par):
    print("\n??? " + par)
    if par == "bar":
        return False
    else:
        return True

def task_bug():
    for par in ("foo", "bar"):
        print("par: " + par)
        # closure!
        exist_fn = lambda: closed_over(par)
        print(exist_fn)

        yield {
            "name": par,
            "actions": [["echo", "action:", par]],
            "verbosity": 2,
            "uptodate": [exist_fn]
        }
```

When I run `doit bug:foo` I expect to NOT execute it as (`closed_over` returns `True`), but:

```
par: foo
<function task_bug.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f8926f9a560>
par: bar
<function task_bug.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f8926f9a5f0>

??? bar      <- par should be foo
.  bug:foo
action: foo  <- echo was called
```

As you can see above the two closures outside the `yield` are different function objects but for some reason `uptodate` is always calling the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating functions in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is regarding python closure scoping (it scope variables not values)... Nothing to do with `doit`. Probably have many questions about this here on Stack Overflow :)

[Python lambda closure scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355233/python-lambda-closure-scoping)

> As you can see above the two closures outside the yield are different function objects but for some reason uptodate is always calling the same.

No, it is not calling same closure. The problem is the same variable as parameter.

Comment: thanks you, I was worried I did not understand something properly

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem seems related to `python`'s closure late binding.

According to a couple of answers in the wild, this is what actually works:

```py
from functools import partial

def closed_over(par):
    print("\n??? " + par)
    if par == "bar":
        return False
    else:
        return True

def task_bug():
    """Test a doit bug."""

    for par in ("foo", "bar"):
        print("par: " + par)
        exist_fn = partial(closed_over, par)
        print(exist_fn)

        yield {
            "name": par,
            "actions": [["echo", "action:", par]],
            "verbosity": 2,
            "uptodate": [exist_fn]
        }
```

```bash
$ doit bug
par: foo
functools.partial(<function closed_over at 0x7f6ab3eb6cb0>, 'foo')
par: bar
functools.partial(<function closed_over at 0x7f6ab3eb6cb0>, 'bar')

??? foo
-- bug:foo

??? bar
.  bug:bar
action: bar
```

---

Thanks Karl for correcting my initial guess.

Comment: This isn't a dynamic vs lexical scoping issue. There are other lexically scoped languages, such as SML (as I learned while closing other duplicate questions), where it would work the way you want. Instead, the issue is that Python is *late binding* for closures: the name is looked up when it is used, not when the closure is created. (A combination of late binding and dynamic scoping would make the problem even worse: the closure could pick up an *entirely unrelated* value for `par` from the scope *where it is called*).

Comment: Thank you this makes more sense indeed, I will update the answer